# using ga() method with GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

My application used Universal Analytics so far, with lots of `ga('send',...)` usage. (for sending custom events to UA).

Now after having more and more tags to implement we decided to use Google Tag Manager.

I've set a Universal Analytics tag (type of Universal Analytics) and in More Setting I've checked Tracker Name (which should allow me access to the ga method as far as I understand).

Thing is it doesn't work and even not implementing the Universal Analytics code.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any other method to set UA in GTM and still keep the usage of ga method, without a need to change all ga methods to dataLayer one.

Would appreciate assistance.

Comment: If it's not even implementing the code you should first check that you have a valid firing rule for your Analytics tag (go to preview, select debug and visit the page in the same browser to see if the tag is fired).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually the problem was that GTM **didn't** load UA on **localhost**, when tried on testing server everything worked as it should be.